# Android EditText focus inside of Fragment within ScreenSlidePageAdapter

Tags: android, keyboard, focus, fragment, fragmentstatepageradapter

[Using the support library]

When attempting to use an `EditText` inside of a `Fragment` that is in my `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` in which multiple `Fragment`s are visible at once.

The second `Fragment` in the list contains an `EditText`. On Android 4.1 & 4.2 it works fine. On Android 2.3.6 (don't know about other versions), tapping the `EditText` will bring up the on screen keyboard, but will not focus the `EditText`. If I drag within the `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` in such a way that the `Fragment` becomes considered "current", then the `EditText` will behave correctly.

A fixed layout is not acceptable, as everything must be generated dynamically and the number of `Fragment`s visible can vary based on different criteria.

Any ideas on how to get it to behave correctly and without hard-coding?

Comment: I've tried the following:

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
     if (v == tv) {
      ((LobbyAct)ChatFragment.this.getActivity()).pager.setCurrentItem(1);
   InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
  }
 }

Which mostly works. But fails whenever another event such as a button press occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
if (v == tv)
```

Of my prior comment needs to be concerned with focus

```
if (v == tv && hasFocus)
```

Full code:

```
if (v == tv && hasFocus) {
    ((LobbyAct)ChatFragment.this.getActivity()).pager.setCurrentItem(1);
    InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
}
```